# Getting Recursion error when compiling code

Tags: python

New to python. I have this code:

```
def maximum(A,l,r):
  if(r-l == 0):
    return A[r]

  lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)//2)
  rmax = maximum(A,l+r//2+1,r)
  print(lmax,rmax)
  if(rmax<lmax):
    return lmax
  else:
    return rmax

A = [9,12,15,5,2]
maximum(A,1,5)
```

when compiling i'm getting this error:

```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
>     maximum(A,1,5)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
>     lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)%2)   File "main.py", line 6, in maximum
>     rmax = maximum(A,l+r%2+1,r)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
>     lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)%2)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
>     lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)%2)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
>     lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)%2)   [Previous line repeated 993 more times]   File "main.py", line 2, in maximum
>     if(r-l == 0): RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I've used this algorithm to convert it to my code:
[image]

Comment: Why do you use modulo operator instead of floor function?

Comment: when using floor also, it gave me the same result @kiner_shah

Comment: You forgot the `(` around `l + r` when finding `rmax`. Also, you call maximum from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong operation

```py
lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)%2)
rmax = maximum(A,l+r%2+1,r)
```

has to be:

```py
lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)//2)
rmax = maximum(A,(l+r)//2+1,r)
```

initially `l` and `r` should be 0 and len(A) - 1 respectively

`print(maximum(A, 0, len(A) - 1))`